Is it possible for puppeteer to take a screenshot without focusing the window? (On windows)
I have a script which makes multiple browsers, and uploads the screenshots at a fixed rate to some API, however when it takes a photo it brings the page to focus. However, I need to occasionally manually go on one of the pages, so the other pages taking screenshots is stealing the focus. Is there a way of preventing puppeteer from stealing the focus?
Here is my test code:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");

async function test() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

  const tasks = Array.from({ length: 5 }).map(async () => {
    const context = await browser.createBrowserContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://example.com/", { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
    while (true) {
      await page.screenshot({ path: "screenshot.png" });
      await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, 2000));
    }
  });
  await Promise.all(tasks);
  await browser.close();
  console.log("all done");
}

test();

I could just put the const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }); function inside the array loop, however the actual library I am using is puppeteer-with-fingerprints which doesnt let you launch as many instances as easily

Focusing the tab to take screenshots should not be required starting from version 23.10.0 https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/packages/puppeteer-core/CHANGELOG.md#23100-2024-12-03
